# Vue.js - pass data to initial Vue and registered components

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I cannot pass data from root `new Vue.js` into registered components

**dashboard.jade**

```
extends /base

block dashboard
  .dashboard
    //- account vue
    account
```

**dashboard.js**

```
 import Account from '../pages/Account';

 auth.on('user:fetched:success', (e, data) => 
   new Vue({
    el: '.dashboard',

    data: {
      user: data.user // some data
    },

    components: {
      Account
    }
  });
});
```

**Account.vue**

```
<template lang="jade">
  .account
    //- layout goes here
</template>

<script>
  import AccountEmail from '../components/AccountEmail.vue';
  import AccountType from '../components/AccountType.vue';
  import AccountExpire from '../components/AccountExpire.vue';
  import PlatformList from '../components/PlatformList.vue';
  import EmailVerification from '../components/EmailVerification.vue';

  export default {
    name: 'account',

    components: {
      AccountEmail,
      AccountType,
      AccountExpire,
      PlatformList,
      EmailVerification
    },

    created() {
      console.log(this.$data); // there is no data :(
    },

    methods: {
      ...
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: You can use props: http://vuejs.org/api/#props

Comment: but how I will pass the necessary data in props from regular jade file?

Comment: This does not work?
`div(
  :data='data'
)`
You will also have to add props to your child component: `props: ['data']`

Comment: I don't know jade, but assuming that @Nora stntax is correct, it should be `div( :userData='user' )`. There the `user`  is your dashboard instance data that you are passing, and the `userData` is the property from the Account component that is receiving the parent data

Comment: @YerkoPalma thanks, you are right! in jade I added `account(:user="user")`, though it's not obvious actually (especially when you switch from react :)